sending password reset using nodemailer in a react application
Everything ive seen on password resets with react is at least two years out of date what am i doing wrong. the following code is everything associated with the password reset and the error im getting is at the bottom
PasswrodResetReq.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useMutation, gql } from '@apollo/client';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST = gql`
  mutation PasswordResetRequest($email: String!) {
    passwordResetRequest(email: $email){
      message
    }
  }
`;

function PasswordResetRequest() {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const [passwordResetRequest, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(PASSWORD_RESET_REQUEST, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setMessage(data.passwordResetRequest);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      setMessage('An error occurred while trying to send the password reset request');
    },
  });

  const handleInputChange = (event) => {
    setEmail(event.target.value);
  };

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    passwordResetRequest({ variables: { email } });
    navigate('/password-reset'); // Navigate to password reset page
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="email"
          name="email"
          placeholder="Email"
          value={email}
          onChange={handleInputChange}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Send Password Reset Request</button>
      </form>
      {message && <p>{message}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default PasswordResetRequest;

PasswordReset.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { useMutation, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const PASSWORD_RESET = gql`
  mutation PasswordReset($token: String!, $password: String!) {
    passwordReset(token: $token, password: $password)
  }
`;

function PasswordReset() {
  const [token, setToken] = useState('');
  const [password, setPassword] = useState('');
  const [message, setMessage] = useState('');

  const [passwordReset, { data, loading, error }] = useMutation(PASSWORD_RESET, {
    onCompleted: (data) => {
      setMessage(data.passwordReset);
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      setMessage('An error occurred while trying to reset the password');
    },
  });

  const handleTokenChange = (event) => {
    console.log(token);
    setToken(event.target.value);
  };

  const handlePasswordChange = (event) => {
    setPassword(event.target.value);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(token, password);
    passwordReset({ variables: { token, password } });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="token"
          placeholder="Token"
          value={token}
          onChange={handleTokenChange}
          required
        />
        <input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          placeholder="New Password"
          value={password}
          onChange={handlePasswordChange}
          required
        />
        <button type="submit">Reset Password</button>
      </form>
      {message && <p>{message}</p>}
    </div>
  );
}

export default PasswordReset;

resolvers.js
Mutation:{
requestPasswordReset: async (_, { email }, context) => {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        throw new UserInputError('User not found', {
          extensions: { code: 'USER_NOT_FOUND' },
        });
      }

      const resetToken = user.createPasswordResetToken();
      console.log(resetToken);
      await user.save();

      const resetURL = `http://localhost:3000/resetPassword/${resetToken}`;
      try {
        await sendEmail({
          to: user.email,
          subject: 'Password Reset',
          text: `Reset your password by visiting the following link: ${resetURL}`,
        });

        // Assuming email sending was successful
        return { message: 'Password reset email sent' };
      } catch (error) {
        // Handle email sending failure
        console.error(error);
        throw new ApolloError('Failed to send email', 'EMAIL_SEND_FAILED');
      }
    },

    resetPassword: async (_, { token, newPassword }) => {
      const hashedToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(token).digest('hex');
      const user = await User.findOne({
        passwordResetToken: hashedToken,
        passwordResetExpires: { $gt: Date.now() },
      });

      if (!user) {
        throw new UserInputError('Token is invalid or has expired', {
          extensions: { code: 'TOKEN_INVALID_OR_EXPIRED' },
        });
      }

      user.password = newPassword;
      user.passwordResetToken = undefined;
      user.passwordResetExpires = undefined;
      await user.save();

      return { message: 'Password has been reset' };
    },
  },
};

module.exports = resolvers;


typeDefs.js
const typeDefs = `
  type User {
    _id: ID
    firstName: String
    lastName: String
    email: String
    profilePictureURL: String
    profileBio: String
    friends: [User]
  }
  type Auth {
    token: ID
    user: User
  }
  type Query {
    users: [User]
    user(_id: ID!): User
  }
  type Mutation {
    addFriend(friendId: ID!): User
    unFriend(friendId: ID!): User
    addUser(firstName: String!, lastName: String!, email: String!, password: String!): Auth
    updateUser(firstName: String, lastName: String, email: String, password: String): User
    login(email: String!, password: String!): Auth
    requestPasswordReset(email: String!): Message
    resetPassword(token: String!, newPassword: String!): Message
  }
  type Message {
    message: String
  }
`;

module.exports = typeDefs;


sendEmails.js
const nodemailer = require('nodemailer');
require('dotenv').config();

const sendEmail = async ({ from, to, subject, text }) => {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'Gmail',
    auth: {
      user: 'iquestcs@gmail.com',
      pass: process.env.PASS
    }
  });

  const emailObject = { 
    from:'"iQuest" <iquestcs@gmail.com>', 
    to: user.email, 
    subject: 'Password Reset', 
    text: `Reset your password by visiting the following link: ${resetURL}`,}
  const info = await transporter.sendMail(emailObject);
  console.log('sent email:', info)
}

module.exports = sendEmail;

server.js
const express = require('express');
const { ApolloServer } = require('@apollo/server');
const { expressMiddleware } = require('@apollo/server/express4');
const path = require('path');
const { authMiddleware } = require('./utils/auth');
const { typeDefs, resolvers } = require('./schemas');
const db = require('./config/connection');
const { User } = require('./models');
const crypto = require('crypto');
const sendEmail = require('./utils/sendEmail');
require('dotenv').config();

const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
const app = express();
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  context: ({ req }) => ({
    token: req.headers.authorization || '',
  }),
});

// Create a new instance of an Apollo server with the GraphQL schema
const startApolloServer = async () => {
  await server.start();

  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
  app.use(express.json());

  // Serve static assets
  app.use('/images', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/images')));

  // Password reset endpoints
  app.post('/request-password-reset', async (req, res) => {
    const { email } = req.body;

    try {
      const user = await User.findOne({ email });
      if (!user) {
        return res.status(404).json({ message: 'User not found' });
      }

      const resetToken = user.createPasswordResetToken();
      await user.save();

      const resetURL = `${req.protocol}://${req.get('host')}/resetPassword/${resetToken}`;

      await sendEmail({
        to: user.email,
        subject: 'Password Reset',
        text: `Reset your password by visiting the following link: ${resetURL}`,
      });

      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Password reset email sent' });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error sending email', error });
    }
  });

  app.post('/reset-password/:token', async (req, res) => {
    const { token } = req.params;
    const { newPassword } = req.body;

    try {
      const hashedToken = crypto.createHash('sha256').update(token).digest('hex');
      const user = await User.findOne({
        passwordResetToken: hashedToken,
        passwordResetExpires: { $gt: Date.now() },
      });

      if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ message: 'Token is invalid or has expired' });
      }

      user.password = newPassword;
      user.passwordResetToken = undefined;
      user.passwordResetExpires = undefined;
      await user.save();

      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Password has been reset' });
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error resetting password', error });
    }
  });

  app.use('/graphql', expressMiddleware(server, {
    context: authMiddleware
  }));

  if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist')));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
      res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/dist/index.html'));
    });
  }

  db.once('open', () => {
    app.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`API server running on port ${PORT}!`);
      console.log(`Use GraphQL at http://localhost:${PORT}/graphql`);
    });
  });
};

// Call the async function to start the server
startApolloServer();

I'm getting this error
POST http://localhost:3000/graphql 400 (Bad Request)
(anonymous) @ @apollo_client.js?v=5558fece:744
Subscription2 @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:1984
subscribe2 @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:2045
(anonymous) @ @apollo_client_link_context.js?v=5558fece:20
Promise.then (async)
(anonymous) @ @apollo_client_link_context.js?v=5558fece:17
Subscription2 @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:1984
subscribe2 @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:2045
complete @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:11089
Concast2.start @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:11118
Concast2 @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:11110
QueryManager2.getObservableFromLink @ @apollo_client.js?v=5558fece:5464
(anonymous) @ @apollo_client.js?v=5558fece:4917
(anonymous) @ @apollo_client.js?v=5558fece:4916
step @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:136
(anonymous) @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:83
(anonymous) @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:69
__awaiter @ chunk-37R5SEUF.js?v=5558fece:51
QueryManager2.mutate @ @apollo_client.js?v=5558fece:4877
ApolloClient2.mutate @ @apollo_client.js?v=5558fece:5941
(anonymous) @ @apollo_client.js?v=5558fece:6864
handleSubmit @ PasswordResetReq.jsx:34
callCallback2 @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:3674
invokeGuardedCallbackDev @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:3699
invokeGuardedCallback @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:3733
invokeGuardedCallbackAndCatchFirstError @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:3736
executeDispatch @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:7016
processDispatchQueueItemsInOrder @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:7036
processDispatchQueue @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:7045
dispatchEventsForPlugins @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:7053
(anonymous) @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:7177
batchedUpdates$1 @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:18941
batchedUpdates @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:3579
dispatchEventForPluginEventSystem @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:7176
dispatchEventWithEnableCapturePhaseSelectiveHydrationWithoutDiscreteEventReplay @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:5478
dispatchEvent @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:5472
dispatchDiscreteEvent @ chunk-HZHRDQM6.js?v=5558fece:5449
Show 35 more frames
Show less


A 400 from Apollo means you are sending invalid GraphQL. Try testing your mutation in the sandbox to ensure you have it correct before doing it in code. Look at your gql code and your variables. Your resolver is never getting hit as the server is rejecting the mutation.
